# Javascript Selector for Collections?

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors

I have this Javascript call:

```
SomeFunction('select#UserInformations_0__CountryId', somefunction(0));
SomeFunction('select#UserInformations_1__CountryId', somefunction(1));
SomeFunction('select#UserInformations_2__CountryId', somefunction(2));
```

Is there any way where I can make the id selector as a template? I currently have a form that gets populated based on a select control selection. Wondering if there's a way to make this more flexible, without exhausting all possible number of indices?

I am working on calling a div based on model collection. When there was a 1:1 relationship between the parent and the child object, the call works well. But as we introduced 1:many, this has been a struggle to implement.

I am not really a javascript guy, the original call is something like this and I just wanted to make it work. I was thinking if the "UserInformations_CountryId" can be make into a template or regular expression.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    SomeFunction('select#UserInformations_CountryId', somefunction());
    // above line works before. I just need to make it work for multiple instances
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "template," but you can certainly use a loop if you like:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    SomeFunction('select#UserInformations_' + i + '__CountryId', somefunction(i));
}
```

If this were setting up an event handler, we could do something more generic, but your quoted code isn't setting up an event handler.

Comment: This is actually loaded when the document is ready. So technically, the loop implementation might not work as expected.

Comment: @Patrick: "Document ready" has nothing to do with this. If the three lines in the question would work, the above would work, full stop. If the above wouldn't work (because the elements weren't yet there, for instance), the three lines in the question also wouldn't work (because the elements weren't yet there, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

You can create the selector in a function and then use that function:

```
function makeSelector(num) {
    return 'select#UserInformations_' + num + '__CountryId';
}

SomeFunction(makeSelector(0), somefunction(0));
SomeFunction(makeSelector(1), somefunction(1));
SomeFunction(makeSelector(2), somefunction(2));
```

Or, you can combine both of those operations into a single operation that just takes the selector number:

```
function SomeFunction(num) {
   var sel = makeSelector(num);
   var other = someFunction(num);
   // ... other code
}
```

And, of course once you're just passing a number, you can use a `for` loop to iterate over multiple selector numbers.

FYI, there's usually no reason to use a selector like `select#UserInformations_0__CountryId` when `#UserInformations_0__CountryId` will be faster and ids are already unique in the page.